# How to get the ascii key sort of rave parameters in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, flutterwave

Ravepay documentation (https://flutterwavedevelopers.readme.io/docs/checksum) shows how to hash values using Nodejs, but I am having issues generating the correct sort order of my getpaidSetup keys, how can I do that in php.

Currently this is my implementation:

```
// In php
$amount_in_naira = $_POST['total'] * 400;
$customer_email = $_POST['email'];
$customer_firstname = $_POST['fullname'];
$txref = 'EX' . '_' . get_current_user_id() . '_' . time();
$integity_str = $pb_key . $amount_in_naira . $customer_email . $txref . $sc_key;
$hash = hash( 'sha256', $integity_str );

// JS
var options = {
    PBFPubKey: '<?php echo $pb_key; ?>',
    amount: <?php echo $amount_in_naira; ?>,
    customer_email: '<?php echo $customer_email; ?>',
    customer_firstname: '<?php echo $customer_firstname; ?>',
    txref: '<?php echo $txref; ?>',
    integity_hash: '<?php echo hash( 'sha256', $integity_str ); ?>',
    meta: [{ metaname: 'merchant_details', metavalue: '<?php echo $metadata; ?>' }],
    onclose: function() {},
    callback: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
}
```

Update:

> From GentlemanMax's answer on ksort, I ran a ksort on an array and
>   compared it to the Javascript equivalent result from
>   `object.keys({payload}).sort()` and results match, see a sample script
>   below showing how to sort by ASCII using Ksort.

```
$pb_key = "FLWPUBK-7adb6177bd71dd43c2efa3f1229e3b7f-X";

$amount_in_naira = 900;

$customer_email = "user@example.com";

$customer_firstname = "user";

$customer_lastname = "example";

$txref = "MV-1838383-JH";

$pmethod = "both";

$options = array(
    "PBFPubKey" => $pb_key,
    "amount" => $amount_in_naira,
    "customer_email" => $customer_email,
    "customer_firstname" => $customer_firstname,
    "txref" => $txref,
    "payment_method" => $pmethod,
    "customer_lastname" => $customer_lastname
);


ksort($options);

var_dump($options);

$hashedPayload = '';

foreach($options as $key => $value){

    $hashedPayload .= $value;
}

$hash = hash('sha256', $hashedPayload);


echo "$hashedPayload\n";

echo "$hash";
```

Comment: There are a few ways you can do this.  It would be helpful to see your existing code and what you have tried so far in order to recommend a solution that would best fit your setup.

Comment: Hi @GentlemanMax currently hardcoding it, but I am looking for a way to sort it using a function like javascript equivalent [`Object.keys({object}).sort()`]

I updated question with my current implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) in PHP will do something similar to `Object.keys({object}).sort()` in js. The most notable difference is that `ksort()` does an "in place" sort of the array.

Assuming that the fields in your code are the only ones you are using, this will do what you are looking for:

```
$options = array(
    'PBFPubKey' => $pb_key,
    'amount' => $amount_in_naira,
    'customer_email' => $customer_email,
    'customer_firstname' => $customer_firstname,
    'txref' => $txref,
);
ksort($options);
$hashedPayload = '';
foreach($options as $option){
    $hashedPayload += $option;
}
```

`$hashedPayload` now contains a string (unhashed) in the correct order for hashing.  It looks like you just need to do a sha256 hash of the string at this point.  Let me know if you need help with that part.

Comment: Hi @GentlemanMax awesome ksort helped, compared the hash input with object.keys().sort() and they match, thanks!